# Make text colored inside EditText

Tags: java, android, colors, kotlin, spannable

Can I somehow color the text inside EditText without using Spannable?
I will be glad to any link.
Now I use Regex for search keywords and dynamically color the text inside EditText. (I use `Kotlin coroutines`)

```
Editable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

But when I open the text from large Text file 600+ lines, my UI starts to slow down.

Comment: so, is the question "I am doing it this way, but it's slow. How can I make it fast?"

Comment: @emerssso I'm already solved my problem, but I don't know how to close the question

Comment: @Danil you can create an answer to your own question, explaining what the solution would be.

Comment: How did you solve the slowness issue? I'm concerned as well